# GNOME 3 only displaying a File menu

Tags: gnome

I just installed GNOME Shell. Only a File Menu is being displayed. GNOME Classic works just fine. Can someone help me? I'd like to have the GNOME 3 user interface.

My system specs are :
Pentium 4 3.0 Ghz, 1GB DDR2 RAM, Intel 82865g with 96 mb video RAM and 3d acceleration.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Could you please describe what you see in greater detail? Perhaps provide a screenshot?

Comment: well... i updated my ubuntu 11.10, and now i get only the desktop background :|
i can't post any images, i don't have enough "reputation"...srry

Comment: Please add this to question

Comment: what should i add to question?

Comment: So you don't have the Panel bar at the top displaying the time and your name in corner?

Comment: press  ctrl +alt+ f1 ,give your user name and password ,then type unity --replace

Answer (score 2):

Try

open the terminal and type

`sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell`
 and then 
`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell`. 
 What method did you use to install the gnome-shell?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the latest Version of the gnome-shell via ppa. That could possibly solve your problem.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```